# Tilemaps not showing up on Android build

Tags: unity, android

I'm having trouble developing a 2d game for Android. I use tilesmaps for the ground and a few other things. On the editor, everything works fine and dandy. But, when I deploy to a phone(Build and Run), the tiles aren't there. It's like they never existed. I go back to the editor and they're there. I play the game directly from the editor and they're there. I even play the game while running unity remote, on the test phone, and the tiles are there. No idea what's going on. This only happens with tilemaps. Everything that isn't a tilemap is visible.  I'm running Unity 2019.3.0f6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I got rid of the tilemap and went with a more tedious approach we were I utilize the snapping feature of unity.  This video is a great source of how to use the snapping feature https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QeEecOc4roI

Answer (score 0):

I found your post a bit late but this might help some others.

I was in the same situation, working fine on Simulator but not on device.
Turns-out it was a silly Z position problem due to the different phones resolutions.

Setting the main camera (assuming you're using an orthographic one) a bit further back in your scene did the trick for me.

Hope that helps!